# LLM's answering out of context ( trained on user data)

Tags: python, nlp, streamlit, langchain, large-language-model

I have trained `LLM` on my PDF file now I am asking questions related to same, but if a question is being asked out of the context I want the answer as " *I don't know* " or " *out of context* "

Right now it is answering even out of context

I have used following embeddings:

1. sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2
2. hkunlp/instructor-xl

and tried with following LLMs:

1. lmsys/fastchat-t5-3b-v1.0
2. falcon-7b-instruct

Here is the

Prompt template :

```
                context: {context}
                question: {question}
                answer: 
                """
                QUESTION_T5_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
                    template=question_t5_template, input_variables=["context", "question"]
                )
            qa.combine_documents_chain.llm_chain.prompt = QUESTION_T5_PROMPT
            qa.combine_documents_chain.verbose = True
            qa.return_source_documents = True
```

Function calling the query :

```
    def answer_query(self,question:str) ->str:
        """
        Answer the question
        """

        answer_dict = self.qa({"query":question,})
        print(answer_dict)
        answer = answer_dict["result"]
```

#### [full code here](https://replit.com/join/lxaofshjga-kvmukilan)

I was trying to upload my data and ask questions based on it but it is answering out of context questions also

Expected outcome: the question you asked is beyond the training data

Answer (score 1):

LLM's don't posses the ability to understand context. So it won't be able to actually decide what is out of context and what isn't.

You can however introduce a confidence system and then refrain from answering if the confidence is below a certain threshold. Now, the LLM itself can't really estimate it's certainty. So you have to work with the "raw" data you already have, which can be very limiting:

Either you calculate the confidence based on the question and compare it to the PDF. or compare the PDF to the answer of the LLM. In either case you could for instance use [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

A rough example by comparing the question and the PDF could be:

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

THRESHOLD = 0.5
CONTEXT = # The parsed data of your PDF (e.g. using pdfplumber)

def answer_query(self, question:str) -> str:
    """
    Answer the question
    """

    question_emb = sentence_transformer.embed(question)
    context_emb = sentence_transformer.embed(CONTEXT)

    similarity_score = cosine_similarity(question_emb, context_emb)

    if similarity_score < THRESHOLD:
        return "I don't know"

    answer_dict = self.qa({"query":question,})
    print(answer_dict)
    answer = answer_dict["result"]
```

This will of course not always be accurate. I'm not sure if there's a better way to solve that problem yet. Some LLM's already provide confidence scores, but they are pretty much useless in this case because that confidence is in another context (e.g. how confident is the LLM, that the next predicted token is the best one)